# Calling a local API from a browser based Silverlight 5 application

Tags: silverlight

I am looking for guidance on ways to implement a Silverlight 5 browser based application that will be able to call a 3rd party API that will read data off a smart card (through card reader API).

So you go to website, hit Silverlight app page and then once it is loaded on your local PC it will be able to access that API and read the data.

I have seen some notes about using COM but not sure if that will work, if it is the right way to go, etc.

Also, if I did have to connect through COM is Silverlight able to install that COM component or would that have to be a separate install?  Trying to avoid having software on the local PC that we have to handle remote release/updates on.

thanks,
Dano

Comment: Another option could be to use p/invoke (SL 5 trusted app, same with COM calls), you could subscribe to folder changes (haven't found that sample) googling you can find how to hook to USB stick plugin for instance, here a sample about how p/invoke works http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/09/05/silverlight-5-rc-platform-invocation.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I am hoping to avoid COM or P/Invoke.  Once i know a bit more about the USB card readers my customer chooses I may have more options.  As an example, if their card reader dumps the contents of the smart card onto a file system on the USB device that would be very easy to access.